Closed form for $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left( \frac{1}{\log(\sin x)}+\frac{1}{1-\sin x} \right)dx$
The integral has the numerical value
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left( \frac{1}{\log(\sin x)}+\frac{1}{1-\sin x} \right)dx=0.86995763688\dots $$
I have been unsuccesfully trying to find a closed form for this, if it exists. The term $\frac{1}{\log(\sin x)}$ directed me towards Feynman's technique, but I couldn't find a suitable place to insert a variable.
In order to make the $\log$ go, one has to consider integrals of the form
$$F(a)=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left( \frac{\sin^ax}{\log(\sin x)}+\frac{g(a)}{1-\sin x} \right)dx $$ which after differentiation evaluates to
$$F'(a)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\cdot\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{a+1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{a+2}{2}\right)}+\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{g'(a)}{1-\sin x} dx$$
But at this point, it seems the first term cannot be integrated back, I tried but couldn't find an antiderivative.
Another approach could be a series expansion of the integrand, and convenientely $\frac{1}{1-\sin x}$  happens to be a nice geometric series. On the other hand, $\frac{1}{\log(\sin x)}$ has revealed to be a tough term to expand as a Taylor series and as a Fourier series as well.
Any help is appreciated! Thank you.

Why do you suppose there exists a usual function for the first summand, there are many functions where only numerical integration works.

$$\dots=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}\big(\log(2n+1)-\psi(2n+1)\big).$$

@AngaeMT the terms alone don't converge, they can't be analyzed separately.

$$\frac{1}{1-\sin (x)}+\frac{1}{\log (\sin (x))}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n,\left(x-\frac{\pi }{2}\right)^{2 n}$$ works except that we do not know the explicit form of the $a_n$

The integrand also seems to be provided by $$\int_0^1 \frac{1-\sin^y(x)}{1-\sin(x)}\textrm{d}y,$$ which you might further exploit.

@Zima, I mean exactly what I wrote: the integral is intended to obtain the integrand of your integral and thus write it all like a double integral. $$\int_0^1 \frac{1-\sin^y(x)}{1-\sin(x)}\textrm{d}y=\frac{1}{\log(\sin(x))}+\frac{1}{1-\sin(x)}.$$ It offers a reduction to integrals involving the Gamma function. The rest remains to be investigated.

@user97357329 My bad,  I didn't see the $\text{d}y$. This is exactly how I obtained the integral in the first place. I was trying to attack the Gamma integral you mentioned.
